# Meaning & Information about Shiva Shiva Shiva Shambho

Tags: shiva, mantras

I'd like to know the meaning of the "Shiva Shiva Shiva Shambho" mantra, which is the effect in the mind as well as its history. Is it part of some ancient text?

Any information about this mantra is highly appreciated!

I've been researching over the internet and the information available is not much, practically none.

Thanks,

Comment: Shambhu from Sham (meaning peace) means "from whom peace is born" or "one who is the source of peace". Another name of Lord Shiva, Shankara, has a similar meaning- One who bestows Sham or peace. Shiva's meaning i think u know already- the auspicious one.